# How do I connect my MS Access database to the LAN?

Tags: database-design, ms-access

I wrote a database program in MS Access a couple of years ago, and it is used to keep track of some personal stuffs. I now want to expand this personal project and allow several computers to have access to this database. Assuming that all I am interested in connecting to are my home computers, i.e. all connected to the same router (same LAN), what are the basic steps I need to do this?

Also, I am very new to database, but I happened to know how to write VBA on MS Access. Is there any tutorial that can help on what I do?

Thanks!

Comment: You will want to split your database into a "back-end" and a "front-end".  The front-end contains any queries, forms, and code you have created.  The back-end contains all the tables, and the front-end accesses those tables through what are called "linked tables".

Comment: @MaxVernon What about the GUI that I made on Access?

Comment: The GUI *is* the front-end.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question and it shows lack of understanding of the technology to mark it so.  The referenced "original" question has _one_ solution to what this question is asking, but it is by no means the only solution nor even necessarily, depending on the circumstances, a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing magical about this.  Just put the Access database file in a file share on your LAN and let people access it from whatever computer they are using.

If you will need to be sure to open the database in shared mode.  Go to the options, select client settings, advanced, and set the default open mode to "shared".  (Depending on your version of access, the way to get to this setting may vary.)

You can do something more elaborate, like segregating your data and your GUI and joining the front end databases to the back end with linked tables, but that may well be overkill.